# Set a method output as parameter of another method in a python class

Tags: python, class, methods, parameters, arguments

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, something_1, something_2=0):
        self.something_1=something_1
        self.something_2=something_2
        
    def SomeMethod_1(self):
        something_2=readsomefile(self.something_1)
        return something_2
    
    def SomeMethod_2(self, data=None):
        try:
            if data is None:
                data = self.something_2
                df = dosometransformation(data)
                return df
        except Exception as e:
            print("SomeMethod_2 error!: "+str(e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SomeClass=SomeClass(something_1)
    SomeClass.SomeMethod_2(SomeMethod_1())
```

I would like to set as parameters of the method `SomeMethod_2()` the output `df_1` of the method `SomeMethod_1()` in the class `SomeClass()`. I don't know where i am wrong but my code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't correctly calling `SomeMethod_1` as a method of the `obj` object.

```
obj = SomeClass(something_1)
obj.SomeMethod_2(obj.SomeMethod_1())
```

Also, don't use `SomeClass` as the name of both your class and an instance of your class; the same namespace is used for both.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my concern is more on how to set as input of the method `SomeMethod_2` the result of the method `SomeMethod_1`. Precisely the parameter `self.something_2`.

Comment: `obj.something_2 = obj.SomeMethod_1()`? If you want `obj.SomeMethod_2` to set the value of `obj.something_2`, that needs to be part of the method's definition.